# Is glucosamine sulfate effective treatment for meniscus injury?

Tags: orthopedics, natural-remedy, injury, knee, tear-of-a-meniscus

I hurt my knee by doing squats. The pain persisted for a long time (3 months). When I went to my doctor, he saw my x-rays which indicated that everything was normal, but he suspected a meniscus tear. He asked me to take glucosamine sulfate for a month.

- Has glucosamine sulfate been shown to be an effective treatment for torn menisci?
- Has this been compared to other treatments such as ice or heat?

Comment: Hi Ajay, we [can't offer personalized advice](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/258/165) so I edited to make this a question of more general interest and keep it from getting closed. Hopefully this will still prove to be informative for you.

Comment: @Susan Good edit. I retracted my close vote.